# Sum subquery Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I'm doing a SQL query and I'm trying to sum the result of my subquery, but without success. The command does not execute
Can someone help me?

The query I'm doing is:

```
 SELECT cm.course_id,cm.course_name, sum (select max(SCORE) from
 ATTEMPT  where GRADEBOOK_GRADE_PK1 = GG.PK1 group by 1)

 FROM gradebook_main gm 
     JOIN course_main cm ON cm.pk1 = gm.crsmain_pk1 
     JOIN gradebook_grade gg ON gm.pk1 = gg.gradebook_main_pk1 
     JOIN course_users cu ON cu.pk1 = gg.course_users_pk1 
     JOIN users u ON u.pk1 = cu.users_pk1

 WHERE U.user_id = '1616894251' 
 group by cm.course_id, cm.course_name
```

Thanks!

Comment: in subquery you declare group by 1  but you have not column in subquery select  clause .. what column you need .. use explicit name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried  build you subselect as joined  table  ..hopre the group by column is GRADEBOOK_GRADE_PK1

```
  SELECT 
        cm.course_id
      , cm.course_name 
      , sum ( t.max_score
      )
  FROM gradebook_main gm 
  JOIN course_main cm ON cm.pk1 = gm.crsmain_pk1 
  JOIN gradebook_grade gg ON gm.pk1 = gg.gradebook_main_pk1 
  JOIN course_users cu ON cu.pk1 = gg.course_users_pk1 
  JOIN users u ON u.pk1 = cu.users_pk1
  JOIN (
     select GRADEBOOK_GRADE_PK1,  max(SCORE) max_score
     from  ATTEMPT  
     group by GRADEBOOK_GRADE_PK1 
  )  t on t.GRADEBOOK_GRADE_PK1 = GG.PK1 
  WHERE U.user_id = '1616894251' 
  group by cm.course_id, cm.course_name
```